# Insert Computer generated output in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Good Afternoon,
I have a CakePHP file(My CTP file in my view) that normalizes judges scores.  Now that the scores have been normalized I want to insert them to a database to later print in a CSV File.  I have tried a couple of different things but nothing has worked.  The goal is to input the normalized scores generated by my code.  I know how to insert user input in CakePHP.  What is giving me trouble is inserting data generated by the code.  I am using CakePHP V2 and MySQL Workbench.  Below is the code I have so far.  It is picking up the normalized scores from an Array then printing them on the webpage

```
if($post['poster']['posterid'] == $current){
            if($count<2){
                $allPresenters[$current] = $post['poster']['author'];
                echo "<tr><td>".$post['poster']['posterid']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$post['poster']['author']."</td><td>".$post['judge']['first']." ".$post['judge']['last']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$allScores[$post['Post']['id']]."</td><td>".$normalizedScores[$post['Post']['id']]."</td></tr>";
                $localTotal += ($allScores[$post['Post']['id']]);  
                $normalTotal += ($normalizedScores[$post['Post']['id']]);
                $count++;       
                //Insert Normalized score here
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>Total Score:</td><td>".$localTotal."</td><td>".$normalTotal."</td></tr>";
            $allNormalScores[$current] = $normalTotal;
            $allScores2[$current] = $localTotal;
            $current = $post['poster']['posterid'];
            $localTotal =0;
            $normalTotal =0;
            $count = 0;
            echo "<tr><td>".$post['poster']['posterid']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$post['poster']['author']."</td><td>".$post['judge']['first']." ".$post['judge']['last']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$allScores[$post['Post']['id']]."</td><td>".$normalizedScores[$post['Post']['id']]."</td></tr>";
            $localTotal += ($allScores[$post['Post']['id']]);  
            $normalTotal += ($normalizedScores[$post['Post']['id']]);
            //Insert normalized score here
        }

    }
```

Below is my model

```
<?php
App::uses("ConnectionManager","Model/ConnectionManager");
class Post extends AppModel{
    public $name = "Post";
    public $belongsTo = array("poster","judge");
    public $validate = array(
        'poster_id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria1' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria2' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria3' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria4' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria5' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria6' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria7' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria8' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria9' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'criteria10' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'comments' => array(

        ),
         'Normalized' => array(

        )


    );

    public function isOwnedBy($post, $user) {
        return $this->field('id', array('id' => $post, 'user_id' => $user)) === $post;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data that you have rendered to the view into the database via `POST`, then you will need to create a form in the page and add the data to your form.

However, if normalizing the data is something that can be done programmatically without user interaction, then I don' see what the need for rendering it to a view is. You could just process it in the model, persist it to the database and then render (if needed) the normalized data to the view.

You really should't be calculating data and figures within views, that's what the model layer is for.

Comment: So I would rather pass by all the methods to normalize and such to the model view controller?  I'll try something along those lines today.  The reason I had it in my view was to show results on a Web Page.  However I was recently asked to import the files to a CSV.  I was just wondering if there was a way that I can just submit all that information to the database with the view since I already have all the code needed there.